# PSReadLine history doesn't load

Tags: windows, powershell, psreadline

I tried to use psreadline today. There is something i don't understand is the history command.

When I run

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource
```

The history suggestions start showing up.

I close the terminal ps, open it again, no history suggestions there until i run the command again.

What do I miss?

Comment: This is not a PowerShell issue or failure. You do not have an issue, what you have is a misunderstanding. So read up on the help files for PSREadline. PSRealine notwithstanding, running command is just for that session unless you set it to options permanently via your profile or automatic variables/preference variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the only command you are using...

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource
```

.. then that is not complete.

As per the Powershell docs here: [MS Docs | PSReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-7.1#:%7E:text=Set-PSReadLineOption%20can%20set%20multiple%20options%20with%20a%20hash,table%20name%2C%20%24PSReadLineOptions%20on%20the%20PowerShell%20command%20line)

```
-PredictionSource
Specifies the source for PSReadLine to get predictive suggestions.

Valid values are:

None: disable the predictive suggestion feature
History: get predictive suggestions from history only
```

So you have to tell it what you want:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource History
```

or

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource None
```

The latter is the default if you don't tell it.
Just put the former in all your console profiles.

```
Get-PSReadLineOption
<#
EditMode                               : Windows
AddToHistoryHandler                    : System.Func`2[System.String,System.Object]
HistoryNoDuplicates                    : True
HistorySavePath                        : C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadLine\ConsoleHost_history.txt
...
PredictionSource                       : None
...
#>
```

Be sure to read up on ...

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -HistorySaveStyle
```

... and its options as well.